# How is every linear function a bijection?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory

I have never had problems understanding bijectivity before, and I still understand it in theory. But I just don't understand how is it possible.
Let me explain. Let's say we have a function, $y=2x$. We know this is a bijection. $x= \frac{y}{2}$, for every $y \in R$ we have an x so we have surjection. Then for $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ we come to the conclusion that $x_1 = x_2$ so it is also an injection. So it is a bijection. I have no problem understanding this.

The problem is when I think about it in real numbers. So let's just consider the part for $x \in [0,1]$. The range is $y \in [0,2]$. For every $y$ in the range we have one respective x, so it is one-to-one. And every y value definitely has a corresponding x, so it is surjective as well. It is continuous in that range and passes the horizontal line test. But what I don't understand is, even though both the ranges $[0,1]$ and $[0,2]$ have infinitely many numbers between them [0,2] range seems to have double the numbers in $[0,1]$ intuitively. Is this wrong? How does this function still can be bijective?

Comment: One key feature of infinite sets is that there is a bijection between it and some proper subset of itself. This is know as Dedekinde infinite.

Comment: Indeed, [a set is infinite if and only if it is equivalent to one of its proper subsets](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Infinite_Set_is_Equivalent_to_Proper_Subset)

Comment: the interval $[0,2]$ has the same amount of numbers as $[0,1]$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Minor quibble: that's actually **not** true in $\mathsf{ZF}$ alone, it requires a bit of the axiom of choice.

Comment: The issue is that many ideas about "size" which play nicely with each other in the finite case become messy in the infinite case. In particular, if we define "$A$ has the same size as $B$" to mean "There is a bijection between $A$ and $B$" - which experience indicates is a **good** choice, ultimately - it is no longer true that $A\subsetneq B$ implies that $A$ and $B$ don't have the same size. More generally, when $A$ and $B$ are infinite we may have a non-surjective injection from $A$ to $B$ even when $A$ and $B$ have the same size, because some *other* injection will be a bijection.

Comment: In general, when reasoning about infinite sets we have to be extremely careful to phrase our definitions precisely and understand that they say only and exactly what they say - things which seem "obvious" based on our experience with finite things may be hard to prove, or even outright false, for infinite things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one seems to want to post an answer, so I'll throw my hat in the ring.

Two big and intricately related ideas in math are *structure* and *transformation.* Which structures are preserved by which transformations?

Bijections, as you're discovering, are a kind of transformation that preserve a certain structure and not much else. This structure, which can roughly be thought of as the number of elements in a set, is known as cardinality. In fact, two sets are said to have the same cardinality precisely when there exists a bijection between them.

You've shown that bijections don't preserve "size" in the sense of length or area. Indeed, the situation is much worse than you might even suspect. A set with $0$ area can be put in bijection with a set with nonzero area. If we want our transformation to preserve area, we have to look at a narrower class of transformations than mere bijections.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was really confused about how they can have the same size but not the same length. I am realizing now that cardinality and length are different. So would linear transformations be in this narrower class of transformations you are talking about? Is there a resource where I can see these classes and their relations (like their narowness, inclusiveness)?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The example you give is a linear transformation, yet it doesn't preserve length. You want something like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_measure
There are so many kinds of structure and transformations in math that any resource trying to describe them all would be impossibly cumbersome. If you want to get your feet wet thinking this way, I recommend studying some abstract algebra. Category theory is really the study of such things, but it may be a bit abstract (I myself have not undertaken a serious study of it).

Comment: But, if you're really curious, there are any number of category theory books that claim to be for the beginner. Find one and see if you can make heads or tails of it.